# What actions will count against the 'I don't need no stinkin' upgrades!" achievement?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

*FTL: Faster Than Light* has the following achievement:

[image: I don't need no stinkin' upgrades! Get to sector 5 with no system/reactor upgrades.]

Reactor upgrades are fairly straightforward, but what counts as a system for the purposes of this achievement?

Furthermore, there are also some events that can trigger upgrades to various systems and the reactor. Sometimes this is a choice, other times it is not. Do these also count against the achievement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the achievement trigger specifically looks at whether you have manually upgraded a system from the Ship's Systems screen, including subsystems that don't require extra power (Doors, Nav, or Sensors).

Random Events that give system or reactor upgrades (such as [Federation Terraforming Team C12](https://ftl.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_Terraforming_Team_C12) or [Slug and Rock Standoff](https://ftl.fandom.com/wiki/Slug_and_Rock_Standoff)) do **not** count against this achievement.

Likewise, purchasing additional weapons or systems (e.g. Drones or Hacking) will not count against the achievement. The Backup Battery is also perfectly fine to use (it doesn't provide permanent reactor power), and can actually be a good choice for trying to earn this achievement.